# JQuery Variable on Timer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select and some code so that the user can select the auto update time.

This is the Javascript code:

```
setInterval(function(){ 

        if ($('#autotimer').val('on')) {

            var millisecondsettings = $('#autoupdateminutes').val();

            submitNewStatsSessionauto();
        }

}, millisecondsettings);
```

And here is the select:

```
<label for="autoupdateminutes" class="select">Auto Update Settings:</label>
<select name="autoupdateminutes" id="autoupdateminutes">
    <option value="60000">1 Minute</option>
    <option value="300000">5 Minutes</option>
    <option value="3600000">1 Hour</option>
</select>
```

Ignore the If part as that works ok.

Is this where the proble is:

```
var millisecondsettings = $('#autoupdateminutes').val();
```

or

Adding the variable where the milliseconds go the issue?

Comment: Where is `millisecondsettings` to come from before the internal function is called ? And your `if` **doesn't** work. This code doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: `Ignore the If part as that works ok.` Well, not really i guess...

Comment: I think he meant that there are no errors coming from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var millisecondsettings` is out of scope. You have to declare it outside the function in order to work. Since it's an internal function that variable is only known there.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
var millisecondsettings = $('#autoupdateminutes').val();
```

means that `millisecondsettings` is local to function. It isn't going to save value after function execution finished. If you are not using `var` keyword then variable will be a property of `window` object (in web context). It's good approach to make you object and store variables in that object. Like `MyApp.millisecondsettings`